# VSO Rest API not returning links

Tags: rest, api, azure-devops

When calling VSO REST api to get one specific workitem

https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/4523?$expand=all&api-version=1.0

links that are under tab Links (image below) isn't returned.

How do I get those links (in this case a hyperlink)?

[image]

Comment: What's the actual result you get? The REST API is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the request lack a `&` char after the work item id `4523`.

The correct format should be:

```
GET https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/4523?&$expand=all&api-version=1.0
```